# python humanclicker will move slowly & won't move in fractions of a second

Tags: python

All I'm trying to do is move from one place on the screen to another, as a human would do, but very quickly...
My code looks like this & doesn't seem to work

```
from pyclick import HumanClicker
hc = HumanClicker()
hc.move((500, 500), 0.04)
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I've looked at some posts: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60006483/python-pyautogui-mouse-movement-in-thread-is-slow-and-unreliable) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65067358/python-pyautogui-humanclicker-mouse-moving-slowly)
They both don't help my issue. if anyone knows the solution, please tell me...

Answer (score 1):

HumanClicker generates a Bezier curve with 100 points to go from your start to your end.  It sleeps between each point for your time period divided by the number of points, which in your case would be 0.0004s, which is below the scheduling threshold.  That means you're going to delay for 100 scheduling intervals, which is a pretty long time.

If you want to move the mouse to a point, just use

```
        pyautogui.moveTo(point)
```

You CAN create your own `HumanCurve` instance and specify fewer points, and then pass that to `move`.

Comment: wow you're awesome! thanks so much for helping me figure this out :)